# Prove the following based on the triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

So I've just proven
$|z_1+z_2|\le |z_1|+|z_2|$

and then I proved

if $a=z_1+z_2$ and $b=z_2$ then $||a|-|b||\le|a-b|$

And now I have to prove the following:

[image]

You can see that the top half is the triangle inequality... but then the bottom is the opposite of the second thing I had to prove. I had a friend that can prove this, only if it's based on the fact that $C\gt D$ but she didn't prove it in the other case where $D\gt C$ so I don't understand what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing $b$ with $-b$ and you get the denominator.

Comment: Hint: if one divides with a smaller number gets bigger quotient.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Thanks, I didn't spot that but then the inequality sign is the wrong way round.

Comment: @JankoBracic and sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say?

Comment: You need to prove the second inequality in general. You have only proved it for particular values of $a$ and $b.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$0\le|A+B|\le |A|+|B|$$
and

$$0<||C|-|D||\le |C+D|$$

so

$$|A+B|\cdot||C|-|D||\le (|A|+|B|)|C+D|$$
and since $|C|\ne |D|$ then $C\ne\pm D$ hence $C+D\ne0$ and the result follows by dividing by $||C|-|D||\cdot|C+D|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is well explained and well justified!!

Comment: You're welcome.